# Simple way to reorder methods of a Java class in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, refactoring, methods, intellij-idea

Is there a simpler way of reordering methods within a class source file in IntelliJ than cutting and pasting the code manually? Nowadays I often need this while refactoring legacy code, e.g. to move related methods close to each other in the source code.

In Eclipse AFAIK there is a view similar to the Structure view of IntelliJ, where I can drag and drop methods around. However, this does not work in IntelliJ and I couldn't find any hints from its help either.

I am using IntelliJ 9.0.2 to be specific.

Comment: I think the best solution would be a formatting tool that orders your methods automatically. Prose: The methods should be orderes in the way they get called. Just like you would read an article in a newspaper.

Answer (score 132, accepted):

You can select a method name and hit: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd> to move it up and down.

On OS X: <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> or <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd>

Beyond this the [Rearranger Plugin](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/173) lets you move methods around quickly, and even define a standard ordering based on your coding convention.

Comment: isnt there something to just reorder alphabetically for example?

Comment: The link is dead, this seems to be the correct one: http://java.net/projects/rearranger

Comment: @stian - I've edited the post to point to the plugin page on JetBrains' website, since the link you posted does not seem to have any downloads available

Comment: For Mac OS X: Cmd+Shift+Up / Cmd+Shift+Down

Comment: The [rearranger plugin does not work well with IntelliJ 2016 versions](https://github.com/DaveKriewall/Rearranger/issues/1) and the bug mentioned in saurabheights' answer is not yet fixed. So it seems there is no way at the moment to rearrange methods automatically in depth-first order.

Comment: Since IDEA 16 it's available through the menu: `Code > Move Statement Up/Down`

Answer (score 46):

IntelliJ has a built in system that allows you to specify how to order your methods. You need to go to Settings (Ctrl + Alt +S) -> Editor -> Code Style -> Java -> Arrangement (tab) and scroll down until you find the icons with `methods`. There you can manipulate the options to sort them by visibility, or alphabetically, or to keep related ones grouped together.
Here is a screenshot of my settings which will order methods automatically by visibility (public, protected, private) and alphabetically (a-z).
The blue highlights show the currently selected rules.

[image]

Comment: How can I apply an order choice to one or more rules at once?

Comment: This does not work at all. Using this config and performing Rearrange does not do anything.

Comment: This solution works with the default ordering. Thanks!

Comment: Pressing "Code -> Rearrange Code" can apply the config to current file at once!

Answer (score 30):

Not a perfect answer **yet**, due to a bug in IntelliJ.

Though IntelliJ offers this feature implicitly, but it needs to be enabled as well as fixed. The OP's suggested way is technically arranging methods in depth-first order. However, if you use Breadth-first ordering(which works properly), it should reduce the manual work of moving functions by a lot, by arranging all caller and callee methods together.

Issue Link: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-149524. Please do vote for its resolution.

[image: IntellijRearrangeMethodsInDFO]

The appropriate action for this is Rearrange Code. This has no key assigned to it, but you can define your own using Preferences->Keymap.

[image: RearrangeActionMenuButton]

[image]

Answer (score 10):

With your cursor on the method definition line (you do not have to  and press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>up</kbd> or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>down</kbd>, to move up or down respectively.

You can also to <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>numberpad -</kbd> to quickly collapse everything so you can focus on moving around (plain <kbd>-</kbd> works on my laptop as well, not sure why) and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>numberpad +</kbd> to get back to see everything (ctrl-shift-equals works on my laptop as well).

Answer (score 7):

Select a block of text (hit Ctrl-W a few times) and then use Ctrl-Shift-Up and Ctrl-Shift-Down to move it around.

Answer (score 2):

There is an automated way, which you can later tweak

Code -> show reformat file dialog

and tick "rearrange code" box